# Change Pulseaudio Log Priority

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, pulse-audio

Hows it goin? I've been dealing with Pulseaudio logs using serious CPU 30-40% at idle the most demanding process running. its /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal I've googled and and found lots of people with the same issue but no real fixes.

If I use system monitor its listed as very high priority I can drop the priority to very low, fixes the issue for the session from 30% to <1%. Any configs to make the priority change permanent?

Mint 20 5.4.0-48-generic

Comment: I ended up working around this issue by disabling its auto-start on boot and just starting it manually when needed it fixed the issue. had the issue on Linux mint w/ mate and Ubuntu w/ mate so maybe it had something to do with mate desktop environment.